# Как не спалить ардуинку с данной схемой?

Tags: arduino

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Сама схема собсна]

Решил сделать небольшое устройство чтобы отслеживать температуру воздуха, влажность воздуха и почвы, освещение. И выводить все на дисплей, но ,как уже понял - все сгорит, если я либо не возьму УНО , либо не организую шину питания и не разведу все. Интересует как раз 2-ой вариант - как это сделать?

Comment: Добавьте принципиальную схему (в Fritzing есть такая кнопка), мне лично лень разбираться с разводкой на макетке.

Comment: P.S. и что-то не понял, почему от I2C дисплея все должно сгореть?

Comment: исходил из того, что подключено слишком много датчиков, как более корректно это определить не знаю, буду рад любой помощи в этой теме, а не -1 к репутации

Comment: принципиальную схему прикрепил

Comment: Мда, такая "принципиальная схема" не поможет. По поводу сгорит или не сгорит - это еще не много датчиков. Посчитать можно так: ищите даташит на каждую из железок, ищите потребляемый ток в описании, все суммируете (по первому закону Кирхгофа), если меньше предельного тока выдаваемого блоком питания (или от чего у вас все питается), то все норм.

Comment: Точнее, т.к. вы вешаете все на +5V, то ищите предельный ток, который можно снять с этого вывода. Остальное все без изменений, предельный ток всех потребителей нужно сложить.

Comment: На мой взгляд самая прожорливая часть на этой схеме - подсветка LCD экрана. Поэтому питать LCD лучше отдельно (или вырубить подсветку).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На ардуино nano стоит микросхема питания [LM1117IMPX-5.0](https://ru.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/LM1117IMPX-50-NOPB?qs=X1J7HmVL2ZGGwLlD0uGqKQ%3D%3D)
максимальный выходной ток 800 мА. Не знаю какой дисплей вы используйте, но для аналогичного ток потребляемый подсветкой 180 мА. Это самый большой потребитель в вашей схеме. Мое мнение 800 мА вам вполне хватит. А вообще советую купить такую [штуку](https://otzovik.com/reviews/voltmetr_usb_charger_doctor/).